# Getting GC overhead limit exceeded when trying to save in mavens mate

Tags: error, mavensmate

Not sure whats happening, but everything was working fine but now when i try to save anything in MavensMate I'm getting "GC overhead limit exceeded" fault errors randomly.  Sometimes i get it five times in a row then i try and save again and it works...

not sure what would be causing it... this is in a sandbox with no traffic other than me and other developer???

Comment: This sounds like a Maven's Mate error, not a salesforce.com error. You may want to contact the authors directly.

Answer (score 1):

There are similar issues seen on cs11.salesforce.com using the latest Eclipse Force.com plugin .  These issues started about 60 minutes ago.  I am not convinced that this is an issue exclusive to MavensMate.

Answer (score 0):

I opened a case with Premier support on the issue. They were able to replicate the internal errors. He didn't try to replicate the Eclipse error, but I explained it to him. Haven't received any response back from them yet though.